# Tomcat, Jenkins, etc. charts in ICP 2.1 install

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I have recently installed IBM Cloud Private 2.1 after trying out ICP 1.2 for a while.  After the new install, I no longer see local-charts options such as Jenkins and Tomcat.  I see the local-charts entry in the repository, but those charts don't seem to be loading.  Thanks...

Comment: When filtering for local charts in the catalog, the list comes up empty.  I've tried synching and restarting the hem-api pod, but no luck so far

Comment: I added the Jenkins chart location manually in the Repositories section (https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins), performed a sync, and then checked the catalog.  The Jenkins chart did not show up either.

Comment: Looking at the helm-api logs in Kibana, I see the following when restarting helm-api:October 30th 2017, 13:17:06.692 2017-10-30T17:17:06.691Z 'ERROR' 'getChartsFromRepo(recursive) error:  Request failed with status code 404'

Comment: I think the URL to the local charts (In my case  https://192.168.1.61:8443/helm-repo/charts) is just plain wrong.  I'm able to load charts from http://charts.bitnami.com/incubator and https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com just fine...

Answer (score 0):

We are porting over the charts and will shortly make them available in our new online repo at https://github.com/IBM/charts.

Comment: Thanks.  I just took a peek at it, and I see all the IBM components but not the open source ones.  Will the open source ones be there as well?

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for the IBM Charts, you can try the open source charts as well.

To be able to deploy jenkins, you can try to add repository as follow. 
Name: stable 
Url: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

For Tomcat, try the incubator from bitnami
Name: bitnami-incubator
Url: https://charts.bitnami.com/incubator

Click sync after you add and you should be able to see the charts in the catalog.

Alternatively, you can download the charts and load it into the local charts with the IBM Cloud Private command line tool (bx pr load-helm-chart).